# Format of Asana Url

Tags: url, asana

Urls in Asana are of the form https://app.asana.com/0/{UNKNOWN_ID}/{TASK_ID}

What is UNKNOWN_ID? Is that in the documentation somewhere (I look, but couldn't find anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually try for yourself what happens if you leave off the last part of the URL - it takes you to the project (or tag, or search) that the task was in, but not the specific task. So, normally, the "UNKNOWN_ID" is the ID of the project or tag you're viewing.